# OpenGL glew list non-core extensions

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glew

I've queried with

```
GLint n;
glGetIntegerv(GL_NUM_EXTENSIONS, &n);

for(GLint i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    const char* extension = (const char*)glGetStringi(GL_EXTENSIONS, i);
    INFORM("Extension #%d: %s", i, extension);
}
```

my supported extensions.

First of all I'm missing the GLX extensions here, how can I query these?

Second how can I filter out core extensions? For example in the list is `GL_ARB_compute_shader`, which is definitely core in Version 4.4.0 (which my context is using).

Comment: as silly as that may seem GLX is an API separate from OpenGL and doing `glGetStringi` will not get you any information about GLX. To query the GLX extensions you'll probably need `glXQueryExtensionsString`

Comment: @PeterT Hmm thanks, looked into it. Seems like this works similar to `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)`. Is there any version working similar to `glGetStringi(GL_EXTENIONS, i)`? Speaking of querying one extension per call instead of all at once in the same string?

Comment: @PeterT: It's even sillier on Windows. You have to create an OpenGL context to load the function necessary to query the WGL extensions... but that function that you have to load is part of a WGL extension ([`WGL_EXT_extensions_string`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/wgl_extensions_string.txt)) - Fortunately, that is the one WGL extension that you *will* see advertised in the `GL_EXTENSIONS` string. Otherwise it would be a total paradox.

Comment: @Uroc327 not that I know of. The whole reason that this was done in OpenGL was, if I remember right, because the list was getting comically long. I don't think GLX has that problem, so they didn't have to fix it.

Comment: You can't really filter out the extensions that have been promoted to core, unless you implement your own logic. You will notice if you ever write GL software for OS X, if you query the extensions string, Apple actually does this. The only extensions they list are things that aren't core in the current context version. Is there any reason in particular that you want to hide core extensions though?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Do you mean an own list of core extensions with own logic? There's no practical motivation for this. Just curiosity :)

Comment: @Uroc327: Yeah, that is what I meant. There is a list of extensions that were promoted to core that you could use to hide everything that's core... but there is no way to ask a GL implementation to do this for you. It's important to note though that the ARB extension is not necessarily identical in form or function to the functionality that is promoted to core. The easiest example I can give you is GLSL (ARB Shader Objects, the original extension has a single function: `glGetObjectParameterARB` that does what `glGetProgramParameter` and `glGetShaderParameter` do in ***core*** GLSL).